# Number of ordered choices of $n$ balls, using exponential generating functions

Tags: combinatorics, generating-functions

I want to understand how I would go about solving counting problems like this

> Use exponential generating functions to determine the number $a_n$ of ordered choices of $n$ balls such that there are 2 or 4 red balls, an even number of green balls, and an arbitrary number of blue balls

I understand how I would start solving this type of problem, getting a multiplication that starts like:
$(\dfrac{x^2}{2!} + \dfrac{x^4}{4!})(\dfrac{1}{2}(e^x + e^{-x}))(e^x)$

corresponding to the red, green, blue balls respectively.

I am aware of an existing  question asking precisely this. However the answer there does not make sense to me [question is here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1551196/exponential-generating-function-and-number-of-balls). Precisely speaking, I cannot understand how the multiplication of the generating functions is expanded in the first expansion in the answer there. Also please note that I cannot comment in the answer to the original question there, since I am a beginner and my reputation doesn't allow me to do that :)

Comment: you can study from [this book](https://www.math.upenn.edu/~wilf/DownldGF.html) how to solve this kind of problems

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understand your question correctly, you want to see the intermediate steps to show that if
$$f(x)={\left(\frac{x^2}{2!}+\frac{x^4}{4!}\right)}{\frac12\left(e^x+e^{-x}\right)}{e^x}$$
then
$$f(x)=\frac12\cdot\frac{x^2}{2!} + \frac12\cdot\frac{x^4}{4!} + \sum_{n=2}^\infty \frac1{16}2^nn(n-1)\frac{x^n}{n!} + \\\sum_{n=4}^\infty\frac1{768}2^nn(n-1)(n-2)(n-3)\frac{x^n}{n!}. \tag{1}$$
OK, here goes:
$$\begin{align}
f(x)&={\left(\frac{x^2}{2!}+\frac{x^4}{4!}\right)}{\frac12\left(e^x+e^{-x}\right)}{e^x} \\
&={\left(\frac{x^2}{2!}+\frac{x^4}{4!}\right)} \frac{1}{2}(e^{2x}+1) \\
&=\frac{1}{2}{\left(\frac{x^2}{2!}+\frac{x^4}{4!}\right)} + \frac{1}{2}{\left(\frac{x^2}{2!}+\frac{x^4}{4!}\right)}e^{2x} \\
&=\frac{1}{2}{\left(\frac{x^2}{2!}+\frac{x^4}{4!}\right)} + \frac{1}{2}{\left(\frac{x^2}{2!}+\frac{x^4}{4!}\right)} \sum_{n=0}^{\infty} \frac{1}{n!} 2^n x^n \tag{2} \\
&=\frac{1}{2}{\left(\frac{x^2}{2!}+\frac{x^4}{4!}\right)} + \frac{1}{2} \cdot \frac{x^2}{2!} \sum_{n=0}^{\infty} \frac{1}{n!} 2^n x^n + \frac{1}{2} \cdot \frac{x^4}{4!} \sum_{n=0}^{\infty} \frac{1}{n!} 2^n x^n \\
&=\frac{1}{2} \cdot \frac{x^2}{2!}+\frac{1}{2} \cdot \frac{x^4}{4!} + g(x) + h(x) \tag{3}
\end{align}$$
where for the sake of keeping our equations short we define
$$g(x) = \frac{1}{2} \cdot \frac{x^2}{2!} \sum_{n=0}^{\infty} \frac{1}{n!} 2^n x^n$$
and
$$h(x) = \frac{1}{2} \cdot \frac{x^4}{4!} \sum_{n=0}^{\infty} \frac{1}{n!} 2^n x^n$$
Then
$$\begin{align}
g(x) &= \frac{1}{2} \cdot \frac{x^2}{2!} \sum_{n=0}^{\infty} \frac{1}{n!} 2^n x^n \\
&= \frac{1}{4} \sum_{n=0}^{\infty} \frac{1}{n!} 2^n x^{n+2}\\
&= \frac{1}{4} \sum_{i=2}^{\infty} \frac{1}{(i-2)!} 2^{i-2} x^i \tag{4}\\
&= \frac{1}{4} \sum_{i=2}^{\infty} \frac{1}{(i-2)!} \cdot \frac{i(i-1)}{i(i-1)} \frac{2^i}{4} x^i\\
&= \frac{1}{16} \sum_{i=2}^{\infty} \frac{i(i-1)}{i!} 2^i x^i \tag{5}
\end{align}$$
and
$$\begin{align}
h(x) &= \frac{1}{2} \cdot \frac{x^4}{4!} \sum_{n=0}^{\infty} \frac{1}{n!} 2^n x^n\\
&= \frac{1}{48} \sum_{n=0}^{\infty} \frac{1}{n!} 2^n x^{n+4}\\
&= \frac{1}{48} \sum_{j=4}^{\infty} \frac{1}{(j-4)!} 2^{j-4} x^j \tag{6}\\
&= \frac{1}{48} \sum_{j=4}^{\infty} \frac{1}{(j-4)!} \cdot \frac{j(j-1)(j-2)(j-3)}{j(j-1)(j-2)(j-3)} \frac{2^j}{16} x^j\\
&= \frac{1}{768} \sum_{j=4}^{\infty} \frac{j(j-1)(j-2)(j-3)}{j!} 2^j x^j \tag{7} 
\end{align}$$
Now substitute $(5)$ and $(7)$ into equation $(3)$, change $i$ and $j$ to $n$, and we have the desired result $(1)$.

Notes:

- $(2)$ by use of the infinite series for $e^x$
- $(4)$ shifting the index in the summation by letting $i = n+2$
- $(6)$ shifting the index in the summation by letting $j = n+4$

Comment: Thanks for the perfectly detailed answer. However, I have a further question. As per my calculations, I concluded that, the coefficient in front of $\dfrac{x^4}{4!}$ (after taking this term "out" of the summation) is $(12 + \dfrac{1}{2})$, whereas in the answer it is supposed to be 13. Have I made a mistake? Or is it meant to be rounded up like that?

Comment: That is, in the answer of the original question which I linked to @awkward

Comment: @d1861323 $13 x^4 / 4!$ is correct. The second term in equation $(3)$ contributes $1/2$ to the coefficient of $x^4/4!$, then $g(x)$ contributes $12$, then $h(x)$ contributes $1/2$, for a total of $13$.